Missing Exchange cmdlet from Powershell module in AutomationAccount
I have a problem that one of the commands I’d like to use is not exists in the Exchange module I can add to an Automation Account. (more specificly is the New-OrganizationRelationship what I’m looking for)
The module I can download from the gallery does not have this cmdlet. The module what I can download is not accepted via upload because I got this error:
Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: Cannot import the module of name exchangeonlinemanagement.3.2.0, as the module structure was invalid. at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext context, Byte[] moduleContent, String moduleName, ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage) at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
How can I have the cmdlet (New-OrganizationRelationship) available in a PS script in a Runbook with AutomationAuccount?
I've tried to download the Exchange modules from the gallery and upload manually.

The account will need to have permissions to see and use the cmdlet. What Exchange Role did you assign?

I'm using an app which has the Exchange Admin role assigned. It is clearly of the missing cmdlet as it stated by the error message :)
New-OrganizationRelationship: Line | 37 | New-OrganizationRelationship -Name $Partner -DomainNames $Domain.Doma … | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | The term 'New-OrganizationRelationship' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
